# gong drag and drop wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

Hello I am usign gong FrameWork from NuGet. But it has some problem, when I drug Item from right to left it's okay. But drug from left to right does not work.

```
<Window x:Class="DragAndDropBehavior.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;assembly=GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closing="Window_Closing">
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="4" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" Margin="5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding .}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Do not look on Serialization

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using GongSolutions.Wpf;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace DragAndDropBehavior
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 

[Serializable]
public class TestSer
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
    public TestSer()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5","6","7","8"};
    }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static public void SerializeToXML(TestSer movie)
    {

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestSer));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\Boxes.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, movie);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
    static TestSer DeserializeFromXML()
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestSer));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Public\Boxes.xml");
        TestSer movies;
        movies = (TestSer)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();
        return movies;
    }
    TestSer Some;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        //Some = new TestSer();
        //Some.Items.Clear();
        //Some = DeserializeFromXML();
        this.DataContext = new TestSer();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        SerializeToXML(Some);
    }
}
}
```

*                                                                             *

Comment: Maybe **AllowDrop** set **true**

Comment: No it does not help's